# javascript doesnt throw error nor display anything

Tags: javascript

Hi can anyone explain the following code 
 javascript doesnt throw error nor display anything

```js
var text = 'outside';

function logIt() {
  console.log(text);
  var text = 'inside';
};
logIt();
```

Comment: It looks to display "undefined", because `var` gets hoisted.

Comment: You have declared the variable again inside the local scope of the function and hence you are getting `undefined` in the console.

Comment: can u please explain me get hoisted mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In function logIt the variable text will get hoisted to the top, so it actually runs like this. It uses the text variable inside the function, which is undefined.

```
function logIt() {
   var text;
   console.log(text);
   text = 'inside';
};
```

Comment: can u please explain me get hoisted mean?

Comment: @Tested when you declare a variable with var, it will be moved to the top of it's scope. you can read more about it here http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: The JS compiler was put all the variables and function declarations to the top of the function(hoist). Hence you are able to use the variable/function before it is defined in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first `text` variable then it isn't possible without parameters. So you have to use the function like this

```
logIt(text);
```

and define it like this

```
function logIt(text){
  //Your Code
  // Now The Variable `text` Is Defined
}
```

Your  Function isn't getting the first variable `text` because a function cannot use variables outside the function without your permission. So,  first text variable is `outside` and if you're trying to get the value of first text variable you have to define it in the function's parameter and if you want to use the second text variable 'inside', then you have to define it before using it.
Like This

```
function logIt() {
  var text = 'inside';
  //Your Code
}
```

So, that's why when your function is executed that time variable is not defined, hence the output is `undefined`. Or else you want to define it at last then you should tell your function that the text variable is defined anywhere in the function by add this line at the top of your function

```
var text;
```

Means a variable that's value will be defined later, so the first finds the value and then executes itself.